# How do I center align a description on top of an image both vertically and horizontally?

Tags: html, css, image

## edit

I should say that I have multiple images I am trying to put in a row.  The solution offered by mdk works but each image appears on a new row.

I have a description and an image.  I am overlaying the description on top of the image.  Currently it is left aligned on the bottom of the image.  I would like to make the description be center aligned both horizontally and vertically, but am having trouble doing so.  The size of the image that is used is 320 x 240.

```
    <!-- image -->
        <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    
    
    <a href="test.html"> <img src = "test.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width: 320px;"></a>
        
        <!-- description div -->
        <div class='description'>
            <!-- description content -->
            <p class='description_content'>This is the description of the image</p> 
            <!-- end description content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end description div -->
    
    </div>
    <!-- end image div -->

</div>
<!-- end wrapper div -->
```

## css

```
div.wrapper{
    float:left; /* important */
    position:relative; /* important(so we can absolutely position the description div */ 
    padding: 5px;
}
div.description{
    position:absolute; /* absolute position (so we can position it where we want)*/
    bottom:0px; /* position will be on bottom */
    left:0px;
    /* styling bellow */
    background-color:black;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:900;
    color:white;
    opacity:0.75; /* transparency */
    filter:alpha(opacity=70); /* IE transparency */
}
p.description_content{
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Is the image always the same size?

Comment: I'm half a sleep right now so I don't want to make a proper answer but here: http://jsfiddle.net/EWzwy/

Comment: @ScottSelby yes the image is always the same size

Comment: @mdk when I try your solution for multiple images consecutively, it puts each image in a new row.  How do I stop this?

Comment: @sharataka It wasn't working properly because you cannot absolutely position within a table cell, a wrapper must be used, I missed this. This should work though: http://jsfiddle.net/EWzwy/2/ Keep in mind this isn't exactly the most semantic markup and also read here if you want to learn more about the problem: http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

Answer (score 0):

if the image is always in same size u can use css top property instead of bottom for example

```
div.description{
                top:130px;
                text-align:center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution showing two images on the same line using display:table on the wrapper, and display:table-cell on the description.  Then you can use vertical-align: middle to vertically center the text.  Using vertical align is better than setting the top, as setting the top to a fixed amount will not take into account multiple lines within the description.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/WSzE2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="test.html"> <img height=240 width=320 src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYm7nE5wc8NLS4tY4zzx-kamyn656ziK8Ma9fnmZLDASZS6oya4g"></a>
    <div class='description'>
        <p class='description_content'>This is the description of the image</p> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="test.html"> <img height=240 width=320 src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYm7nE5wc8NLS4tY4zzx-kamyn656ziK8Ma9fnmZLDASZS6oya4g"></a>
    <div class='description'>
        <p class='description_content'>This is a multi line description of the image. abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper{
    float:left; /* important */
    display: table;
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}
div.wrapper img {
    position: absolute;   
    z-index: -100;        
}

div.description{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; /* to vertically center */
    text-align: center; /* to horizontally center */
}
p.description_content{
    color: white;
    background: grey;
}
​
```